# How to render index.html normally when using DAV SVN?

Tags: svn, apache2, webdav

I have the DAV SVN Apache module running so that I can serve a read-only version of my repositories over HTTP.

My goal is to be able to show available HTML-based code documentation (javadoc, etc.) in my repositories using the browser's normal HTML rendering capabilities, instead of the files being spat out as plain text by the DAV SVN module.

Is there a way to set this up in the Apache .conf files without having to recompile any modules from scratch, or installing any other modules/tools?

I tried adding "DirectoryIndex index.html" but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the docs on that here:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.browsing.mimetype

Basically, apache is serving it as the mimetype SVN knows for the file, which defaults to plaintext. If you tell SVN what type those files are, or tell it to guess the mimetype, apache will serve the proper one.

I think you want to set

```
enable-auto-props yes
```

in your config, and make sure the autoprops section has the correct entries for the file types you expect to be serving (html, css, images, etc.).

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config